# fixed Navbar goes down when go mobile bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

im newbie in this, but im trying... hehe

so, im working in a new version of this webpage but i stuck in this point, see this:

[chileansoftware test page](http://www.chileansoftware.cl/2014)

well, if you see its the skeleton ok, but if you go mobile (like 300px) the carousel (every carousel version, jquery/bootstrap/etc) goes down like 20 px and i dont know how why!!

im tried looking in the forum but i dont found an anwser, im stuck so

if you read thanks!
if you help me thanksx2!

Comment: You should post some code as well as the link. A lot of security conscious people won't follow that link as it could be anything. You'll be able to get more help/answers that way. :)

Comment: i made the changes like greek not silly help me and worked, and thanks alan006 for the tip, for the next question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This div:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-default visible-xs" role="navigation" style="
    margin-bottom: 0px;
">
```

Is having a 20px margin-bottom.

in your style.css do the following:

```
.navbar-default {margin-bottom: 0px;}
```